# Fix width and height of prettyPhoto

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

How can I fix Height and Width  of Inline content showing in a popup by prettyPhoto and I also want to change button postion from bottom to top right position.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oxCB.png

I am using following code but it is not working height is more then 200px:-

```
    jQuery("a[class^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                social_tools: false,
                theme: 'light_square',
            default_width: 300, //I have tried playing with these values
            default_height: 200, //I have tried playing with these values
              });
  <div class="fom"><a rel="prettyPhoto[rounded]"  href="#inline_demo0">Impm </a></div> 
  <div id="inline_demo0" style="display:none;">

   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  </div>
```

Any Help Should Be Appreciated.

Comment: and where is your code? what have you tried ?

Comment: @LuisTellez Please check the code